# Plotting networkx and nxvis graph side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot these two images side by side:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nxviz as nv

test_G = nx.tutte_graph()
nx.draw(test_G)
plt.show()

m = nv.MatrixPlot(test_G)
m.draw()
plt.show()
```

I tried using:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,1))
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
...
```

but this creates a new set of axes, is there a standard way to plot images side by side, `plt.figure` approach seems to work only when I want to create the plot (such as plotting tuples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nxvis is badly designed. It creates its own hardcoded 111 subplot in a fresh figure. An option may be to first create the nxvis plot and then change its position according to a gridspec.

(Again I haven't tested this, because I cannot install this nxviz package)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nxviz as nv
import matplotlib.gridspec

test_G = nx.tutte_graph()
m = nv.MatrixPlot(test_G)
m.draw()


gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2,1)
plt.gca().set_position(gs[1].get_position(plt.gcf()))
plt.gca().set_subplotspec(gs[1])

plt.subplot(gs[0])
nx.draw(test_G)

plt.show()
```

Comment: doesn't quite work, there is a blank empty plot in between

Comment: ok, I cannot test it, because I don't know what nxvis is. Can you link to a documentation of that?

Comment: Oh I see. nxvis is badly designed. It creates its own hardcoded 111 subplot in a fresh figure. Do you really need to use it?

Comment: ahh..that's annoying.. it makes generating nice plots quite easy, not sure of another package that does similar stuff

Comment: almost, I think I can play around with that to get it right though, thanks!